# Upload pre-installed app to playstore shows error

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-console, preload

While uploading app on Google playstore, we are getting below error.

> You need to use a different package name because [pkg_name] is used by
> a pre-installed application. To upload a pre-installed application,
> please contact Google Play Developer Support.

I am sure that mentioned pkg name is unique, however we have pre-installed this app in some of devices. Now how to upload it to Play console ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved by using contact support team of Google, They then contacted carrier/preload team to allow package.

Sometimes if you preload app first and then publish app on Playstore, Google play will block the package and confirm your identity from pre-load team before allowing you to publish.
So it is advised to put package in store first & then pre-load to avoid such long process. (You can limit discovery via multiple ways).

Source - https://medium.com/@shashank.mishra_62841/complete-guide-in-app-update-for-android-apps-google-playstore-1b8f2946fa7a